# How can I set the schema in a wsdl to correctly parse a list of items?

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, wsdl, schema

I've searched intensively and didn't find how to address this: 
I have a web service that needs to accept a list of items like this:

```
<registrationform>  
    ...
    ...
    <registerdoclist>
        <registerdoc>
            <date>2015-10-27</date>
            <doctype>CC</doctype>
            <filename>document1.pdf</filename>
            <filecontent>JVBERi0xLjUNCi1tb1DQoxIDAg</filecontent>
            <extrainfo>document A</extrainfo>
        </registerdoc>
        <registerdoc>
            <date>2015-10-27</date>
            <doctype>CC</doctype>
            <filename>document2.pdf</filename>
            <filecontent>IHRydWU+Pj4+DQplbmRvYmoNCjI</filecontent>
            <extrainfo>document b</extrainfo>
        </registerdoc>
    </registerdoclist>
    ...
    ...
</registrationform>
```

The schema is configured this way (only relevant parts):

```
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="registerdoclist" nillable="true" type="tns:registerdoc"/>


 <xs:complexType name="registerdoc">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element  minOccurs="1" name="date"          type="xs:date"/>
                <xs:element  minOccurs="1" name="doctype"       type="tns:Alfa3Type"/>
                <xs:element  minOccurs="1" name="filename"      type="tns:Alfa255Type"/>
                <xs:element  minOccurs="1" name="filecontent"   type="xs:base64Binary"/>
                <xs:element  minOccurs="0" name="url"           type="tns:Alfa255Type"/>
                <xs:element  minOccurs="0" name="extrainfo"     type="tns:Alfa255Type"/>                    
            </xs:sequence>
           </xs:complexType>
```

When I generate the webservice java objects, in the registration class, the registerdoclist seems to be ok, as it's a list of Registerdoc objects:

```
@XmlElement(nillable = true)
protected List<Registerdoc> registerdoclist;
```

And the Registerdoc class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "registerdoc", propOrder = {
    "date",
    "doctype",
    "filename",
    "filecontent",
    "url",
    "extrainfo"
})
public class Registerdoc {

    @XmlElement(required = true, type = String.class)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(SctdXmlGregorianCalendarAdapter.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar date;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String doctype;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String filename;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected byte[] filecontent;
    protected String url;
    protected String extrainfo;
    ...
    ...
```

In the registrationform object I have a list named registerdoclist of registerdoc objects that apparently match the xml structure to parse, but when I call the webservice, I get this error:

```
 <faultstring><![CDATA[Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"registerdoc")
```

So, what's wrong with the schema and How can I configure it in a way that it parses correctly the sample xml in the list registerdoclist shown above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML contains `<registerdoclist>...</registerdoclist>` elements containing the elements `<date>` etc., so the collection wrapper level of XML elements is missing.

You need an additional class to hold the `List<Registerdoc>`:

```
<xs:element name="registerdoclist" type="tns:registerdoclist"/>

<xs:complexType name="registerdoclist">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"
                name="registerdoc" type="tns:registerdoc"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```